# Login program with java with error

Tags: java, authentication

I'm new to java and I am making a login program (based on text file processing) as part of my Java assignment so far I have written this code but it only checks the first line in the text file. I have also tried to add a for loop but it didn't work either.

Could you please help me fix this problem.

(username and password are separated by a tab character in the file that's why I used this (user+"\t"+pass))
Already tried the web, I didn't find any good tutorial.

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        if ((user+"\t"+pass).equals(strLine)) {System.out.println ("Sucess");}
    }
```

the text file is so

```
 x  y
 x  z
 x  t
```

so when you enter x and y the program says Success but for x and z or t there is no result!

Comment: Seems to work just fine. You should post the contents of your file.txt.

Comment: This problem was just solved , thanks everyone

Comment: You could accept the answer that helped you solve the issue.

Comment: you may accept one of the answers as the answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Delete {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/file.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    String user = "john";
    String pass = "doe";
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if ((user + "\t" + pass).equals(strLine)) {
            System.out.println("Sucess");
        }
    }

}
```

}

And the file.txt:

```
john    doe
john    doe
john    doe
mary    doe
```

As you would expect, the console output is:

```
Sucess
Sucess
Sucess
```

So the piece of code you posted does check all lines. Please paste the contents of your file and your user and password strings.

Comment: Make sure all the user \t password pairs are on a single line. The source code you posted is fine.

Comment: Thanks buffalo a lot, the text file was a bit messed up, as you said the code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are expecting tab but found consecutive space or vice versa.check that.

```
String str="abc"+"\t"+"def";
System.out.println(str.equals("abc  def"));//this is tab so it is true
```

but below is not true

```
String str="abc"+"\t"+"def";
System.out.println(str.equals("abc    def")); //this is space so it is false
```

Comment: No it's just tab , if the entry equals the first line the program works well but it never check the second line!

Comment: you may post contents of your file to help you better

Comment: @bluesky is it like that only first is right ,rest are wrong or you want all correct ?what is ur expectation.

Comment: first one was separated by a tab but the rest weren't, so that's why it didn't work , now it's working well :D

Comment: I asked you that specifically, proved you the source code you posted works. You said it didn't. I'm speechless.

Answer (score 0):

If you know something about swing components then please go though this link

http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/7050-Login-Form-in-Java.html

and if you don't know then i suggest you, you must try learn basic concepts of java by using logical programs.

You are talking about login form. You must try this when you learn something about UI related things..

You must know database connectivity while designing login from application...

Hope, this is clear to you..

Answer (score 0):

in your text file all the data is in a single line... the readLine() method would move to the next line in each iteration.. it would work if your data is

```
x     y

x     z

x     t
```

rather than

```
x    y     x      z     x    t
```

and make sure your text file is in the same directory as your .class file (as your code expects)